# website on Azure not Accessible due to www coming before websitename azurwebsites net

Tags: magento, url, dns, url-routing, azure-web-app-service

I have uploaded a Magento website to Azure website. It was working perfectly fine with websitename.azurewebsites.net
But when i tried to use a custom domain(I did the dns thing also). Whenever i go to the custom domain or with .azurewebsites.net it redirects to www.websitename.azurewebsites.net
Why is the www coming before websitename.azurewebsites.net ?
[image: This is what is happening]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You configured your DNS with CNAME

> www.websitename.azurewebsites.net

Check the guide you followed for DNS configuration and make sure "www" in the front is removed.